# Which were the (militarily) strongest countries of the Holy Roman Empire?

Tags: military, holy-roman-empire

The Holy Roman Empire was neither holy, Roman or an empire, but it was still a strong power despite its infighting. What were the strongest countries towards the end of the "empire"?

Comment: "The Two Headed Eagle": Germany and Austria.

Comment: @user14394 - I don't believe "Germany" was a country of the Holy Roman Empire.

Comment: Berlin sure was....

Comment: It lasted for quite a time, with power constantly shifting. You should specify an historical moment for the answer to be answerable.

Comment: The Holy Roman Empire officially ceased to exist in 1806. "Toward the end" Prussia was definitely a major force.

Comment: @user14394: Berlin is not a "country". It was the capital of the Kingdom of Prussia though.

Comment: My vote goes to Prussia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Austria and Prussia. They were the only major powers during this time which were also part of the Holy Roman Empire. Other countries like bavaria, saxony or Hessia were minor powers.

[Here is an "indirect" source](http://www.napoleonguide.com/armyind.htm): The site shows the major armies of the involved countries of the Napoleonic Wars. Two of them (Austria and Prussia) are part of the Holy Roman Empire (HRE). If there were other strong countries within the HRE they would be listed here, also.

Comment: My issue with listing Prussia here is that they weren't really a country until the 1700's and most of their territory (including the entire Dutchy of Prussia) was outside of the HRE. So for the HRE's 1000 year existence, Prussia really only vaguely deserves this status in the last 100. When you think of the HRE, you usually think of the Middle Ages, and there was no "Prussia" in it in the Middle Ages.

Comment: @T.E.D. while I do agree, I did ask about the end of the empire

Comment: @UncleTres Ah, my bad. I didn't reread the question after you edited it to add that phrase.

Comment: @T.E.D. that's okay

Comment: Its "Hessia"? I thought it was spelled "Hesse".